# No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I had installed Python 3.5 from anaconda distribution.

```
C:\Users\ananda>python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC     v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I am importing matplotlib on jupyter notebook,where I am getting error related to module not found.

I tried to install matplotlib like below:

```
>>>C:\Users\ananda>conda install matplotlib
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ananda\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:
matplotlib                1.5.1               np111py35_0
```

Not sure whats wrong I am doing,how to use matplotlib module here,do i need to install any particular version?

Comment: Did you actually try to import `pylot`?  Because the module is called `pyplot`.

Comment: oops,sorry for this silly mistake....

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt to install `matplotlib` seems right, but the submodule you're looking for is called `pyplot`.

Just try:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> # No ImportError or similar, everything is fine
```

If you still get an error, just post the **full** traceback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: >>> import matplotlib.pylot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'

I am getting still error

Comment: oops this was pyplot,sorry for typo

Answer (score 0):

```
even after having the matplotlib module if u get this error then try:
```

from matplotlib import pyplot

c = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

pyplot.plot(c)

pyplot.show()

```
to check whether the matplotlib is installed or not,**go** to your anaconda 3 folder where u have installed then go to lib then go to site packages then check for matplotlib folder if u find it then the above process works fine i.e., from matplotlib import pyplot 
if u don't find then go to anaconda prompt or command prompt then install the matplotlib using pip install matplotlib.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the submodule pylot instead of pyplot. its justa simple typo err
anaconda should already have it installed so just run your cell again and wait while Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.